# R - How to pass parameters to function in "mutate across"?

Tags: r, string, date, dplyr, across

I have a dataframe which contains multiple columns with date-values as strings (format: YYYYMMDD).

```
dt_example <- data.frame ( 
    W03 = "20201130",
    W44 = "19711031",
    P01 = "19740813",
    P04 = "20000506",
    Z02 = "20201231"
  )
```

Now I want to convert the strings to date-format and tried the following code which works fine:

```
dt_example_date <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    W03 = as.Date(W03, "%Y%m%d")
    ,W44 = as.Date(W44, "%Y%m%d")
    ,P01 = as.Date(P01, "%Y%m%d")
    ,P04 = as.Date(P04, "%Y%m%d")
    ,Z02 = as.Date(Z02, "%Y%m%d")
  )
```

But this code is annoying and I want to use "mutate across" instead of mutliple as.Date-conversions.

I've tried several alternatives, but nothing works.

```
dt_example_date_2 <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c("W03","W44","P01","P04","Z02")
      ,as.Date
    )
  )
```

Result: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

```
dt_example_date_2 <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c("W03","W44","P01","P04","Z02")
      ,as.Date(format="%y%m%d")
    )
  )
```

Result: argument "x" missing

```
dt_example_date_2 <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c("W03","W44","P01","P04","Z02")
      ,as.Date(., format="%y%m%d")
    )
  )
```

Result: do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

I didn't get it and don't know, what to do.

How can I pass paramaters to the function used within the across-command?

Greetings
Benne

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#Code
dt_example_date_2 <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c(W03,W44,P01,P04,Z02)
      ,~as.Date(.,format="%Y%m%d")
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
dt_example_date_2
         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

To avoid typing all names you can try this (Many thanks and credits to **@latlio**):

```
#Code 2
dt_example_date_2 <- dt_example %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      everything()
      ,~as.Date(.,format="%Y%m%d")
    )
  )
```

Same output.

Comment: You can also specify `everything()` in this case instead of typing out all the column names!

Comment: @latlio You are totally right, I will add that to the post with credit to you! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone.

The first solution fits best.

Answer (score 2):

a) you need to pass the format argument comma-separated.
b) you had a typo in your format (lowercase "y" instead of uppercase).

```
dt_example %>%
  mutate(across(c("W03","W44","P01","P04","Z02"), as.Date, format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

gives:

```
         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't known to pass args as comma-separated.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution: You can simply pass the structure directly to as.Date if you convert it to a matrix before.

```
dt_example_date <- as.Date(as.matrix(dt_example), "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "2020-11-30" "1971-10-31" "1974-08-13" "2000-05-06" "2020-12-31"

str(dt_example_date)
#  Date[1:5], format: "2020-11-30" "1971-10-31" "1974-08-13" "2000-05-06" "2020-12-31"
```

or preserving dataframe structure:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(X = dt_example, FUN = as.Date, "%Y%m%d", simplify = F))
#         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
#1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `across` with `everything()` like below

```
> dt_example %>%
+   mutate(across(everything(), as.Date, format = "%Y%m%d"))
         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

---

A `data.table` option is

```
> setDT(dt_example)[, lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%Y%m%d")]
          W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1: 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

---

A base R option using `list2DF` + `Map`

```
> list2DF(Map(as.Date, dt_example, "%Y%m%d"))
         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate package:

```
data.frame ( 
  W03 = "20201130",
  W44 = "19711031",
  P01 = "19740813",
  P04 = "20000506",
  Z02 = "20201231"
) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), lubridate::ymd))
```

This gives:

```
         W03        W44        P01        P04        Z02
1 2020-11-30 1971-10-31 1974-08-13 2000-05-06 2020-12-31
```